# How can I enable debug log mode for a single module or sub module in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Our TeamCity build executes a build script that looks something like `mvn --batch-mode  --file root/pom.xml --settings /home/work/maven/settings_build2.xml ..... install`

The root `pom.xml` has 100's of child modules under it, my requirement is to run one such module (pom.xml) with logging in debug mode without changing my build command (`mvn -batch mode`), is it possible ?

Say, `testing` is the intended sub module, for which logging level should be debug. Is it possible to add that in testing's pom.xml ?

Comment: Which logging level ? For your code or for Maven?

Comment: @khmarbaise : for Maven

Comment: Why ? What's the problem? Just testing local to find a bug in Maven? Why activating debugging output for Maven?

Comment: @khmarbaise
One particular module while downloading a dependency artifact is failing intermittently.
`* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6.`

Comment: Network.../firewall/proxy issue... furthermore don't you have a repository manager in place? Furthermore this: `configuration ':compileClasspath'` looks not like a Maven output? And apart from that why haven't you added this information to the post ?

Comment: @khmarbaise :I thought it might unnecessarily complicate the original question. That specific java module(`testing`) is built in gradle, but invoked as mvn project during the build execution using gradle-maven plugin.
Yes, we have our internal  repository manager in place & the build fails intermittently while downloading from there.

Comment: Sorry to say. That does not make sense (why having 100 modules with Maven and then using Gradle in the middle).. build that module with Maven too or migrate the whole build to Gradle if you like... and of course it's important ... because that means the configuration Gradle is not correct... and can not work because you are only offering a configuration for Maven (via settings.xml) apart from using `mvn install` ??? (why is that needed?) What kind of tests are done in that module? Why not using Maven for unit- and integration testing ?...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241614/discussion-between-goku-and-khmarbaise).